# capture and post image into page album in iOS

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-page

I am trying to post image in to page album , i used this  /{album-id}/photos to post image in to particulate page album , but using this i can post into profile album . how i can post image into page album . i used this code for post:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:image, @"source",nil ];



 /* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/607843282662042/photos"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          )
                    {


                          /* handle the result */

                          NSLog(@" %@", result);

                          self.uploadingText.alpha = 0;

                      }];
```